# How to install jena framework on windows?Does it need eclipse to be installed already?

Tags: eclipse, jena, ontology, protege

I want to develop ontology using jena framework and protege tool so that i need to install jena framework first. and i am not getting exactly how to install jena from installation guide.

Answer (score 2):

No, Jena does not need Eclipse. You do not need to 'install' Jena, it is just a set of libraries that you will refer in your classpath. All you need to do is download them.

Comment: Yes Ignazio I have already set jena root an jena home class variables. Thanks for your response